# How can I find a specific line in a file without using regular expressions in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I have a file that I want to read in using the [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp) module then search that file for a specific line. I know Perl has regular expressions but the strings I’m searching for are user-generated so don’t want to have to worry about escaping everything. I could write a foreach loop to do this but was wondering if there’s a function in Perl that will do this for me? Everything I see online about finding text in Perl uses regular expressions.

Comment: It's like asking "How can I drive to the shops without using my car?"...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just use a regular expression. You don't have to worry about escaping everything, Perl has the [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function for that (or alternatively, "\Q\E").

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
use List::Util qw<first>;

my $line 
    = first { index( $_, $something_users_are_looking_for ) > -1 } 
      <$file>
    ;
```

And if you want 'em all.

```
my @lines
    = grep { index( $_, $something_users_are_looking_for ) > -1 } 
      <$file>
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a string literal using q()?

```
print(q(This string can contain regex: (\n\t*\n)(\n)));
```